# Ошибка JavaScript на сайте

Tags: javascript, яндекс-метрика

Проблема заключается в том, что на [сайте](https://warp.fun) происходит ошибка javascript в коде, который я даже не добавлял.

```js
<script id="er5tnh">
(function(){

    if (window.self !== window.top)
        return;

    (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)};
       m[i].l=1*new Date();k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)})
       (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");

       ym(62788399, "init", {
            clickmap:true,
            trackLinks:true,
            accurateTrackBounce:true
       });

    var el = document.createElement("img");
    el.src = "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-159821570-1&dh=test2.comm&cid=#userid#&dp=/" + encodeURIComponent('api5f5f72b03179b5.95765241') + "/web_ping/" + document.domain;
    document.body.appendChild(el); // ошибка тут line 40

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var tmp = document.getElementById("er5tnh");
        if(tmp && tmp.parentNode)
            tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);

        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src = "/s3/static/partners/main.js?p=" + encodeURIComponent('api5f5f72b03179b5.95765241');
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    });
})(); // line 51
```

На выходе получается ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at (index):40
at (index):51
```

Насколько я вижу из кода, то это Яндекс Метрика. Я пробовал удалить свой сайт оттуда, но ошибка не уходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть причиной, и как это исправить. Из-за этой ошибки другой код js не выполняется.

Comment: Это не Яндекс, это Гугл.Аналитика. Но дело не в ней. Вопрос только в том, куда же делся document.body? =) Я бы переместил оба скрипта под строчку с DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю, что произошло, но ошибка пропала сама собою, даже без моего участия. Это полтергейст, никак иначе.